# Sencha Touch Variable Missing error

Tags: json, sencha-touch

In an effort to learn more about Sencha Touch I am building a calendar webapp for our university. I have some scripts that work but the problem is when I try to update the listPanel with the JSON data from Events.php. I am getting the data from the page but the update command is not updating the listPanel and instead for some reason that I can't put my finger on is asking for the events variable which is commented out.  Now if I uncomment that variable it will parse the JSON in that variable but for the life of me i have no idea why.

Here is the the index.html

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Student Calendar</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/ext-touch.css" type="text/css"/>   
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/ext-touch.js"></script>  
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/calendar.js"></script>   
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/calendar.css" type="text/css"/>
</head>
<body>

<textarea id="eventList" class="x-hidden-display">
    <ul id="eventsItems">
        <tpl for=".">
        <li class="date">
        {date}
        <li>
        <tpl for="events">
        <li>{title} - {location}</li>
        </tpl>
        </tpl>
    </ul>
</textarea>

<textarea id="eventList" class="x-hidden-display">
    <ul id="eventsDescriptionList">
        <tpl for=".">
        <li class="date">
        {date}
        <li>
        <tpl for="events">
        <li>{title} - {location}</li>
        </tpl>
    </ul>
</textarea>

<textarea id="eventDescription" class="x-hidden-display">
        <tpl for=".">
            <p>{title}</p>
            <p>{description}</p>
            <p>{location}</p>
            <p>{startTime}</p>

        </tpl>

</textarea>


</body>
</html>
```

Here is the calendar.js

```
Ext.setup({
        onReady:function(){

            eventListTemplate = Ext.XTemplate.from("eventList");
            descriptionTemplate = Ext.XTemplate.from("eventDescription");

            eventTapHandler = function(eventer,tapped){
                tapID = tapped.id;  
                /*Pass Into The Ajax Portion for getting a events description*/
                Ext.Ajax.request({
                params:{
                    /*params are available inside of the Ajax request*/
                    needs:eventDescription,
                    panel:"descript",
                    id:tapID,
                    fails:rootPanel
                },
                url: 'Events.php',
                method:'POST',
                success: function(response, opts) {
                    /*Ext.uitl.JSON.decode() is used to change the response text to a JSON object*/
                    opts.params.needs.update(Ext.util.JSON.decode(response.responseText));
                },
                failure: function(response, opts) {
                  alert("Sorry There Was An Error");
                  opts.params.fails.setCard(0);
                }
                });             
                rootPanel.setCard(1);       
            }

            eventBackHandler = function(){

                rootPanel.setCard(0);
            }

            backButton = {
                text:'Back',
                ui:'back',
                cls:'.backable',
                handler:eventBackHandler
            }

            toolBarBack = new Ext.Toolbar({
            dock:'top',
            title:'Event Desciption',
            cls:'toolBar',          
            items:[backButton],

            });

            listPanel = new Ext.Panel({
            tpl:eventListTemplate,
            scroll:'vertical',
            tester:function()
            {
                alert('MAGIC');
            },
            getEvent:function(){
                var currentPanel = this;
                Ext.Ajax.request({
                    params:{
                        /*params are available inside of the Ajax request*/
                        panel:"list",
                        needs:currentPanel,
                        fails:rootPanel
                    },
                    url: 'Events.php',
                    method:'POST',
                    success: function(response, opts) {                 
                    var data = Ext.util.JSON.decode(response.responseText);
                    //opts.params.needs.tester();
                        /*Ext.uitl.JSON.decode() is used to change the response text to a JSON object*/
                        opts.params.needs.update(data);
                    },
                    failure: function(response, opts) {
                      alert("Sorry There Was An Error");
                    }
                });


            },
            listeners: {el: {tap: eventTapHandler,delegate: '.touchable'}}

            });

            eventDescription = new Ext.Panel({
            tpl:descriptionTemplate,
            scroll:'vertical',          
            dockedItems:[toolBarBack]
            });         


            rootPanel = new Ext.Panel({
            fullscreen:true,
            layout:"card",
            animation: 'fade',
            items:[listPanel,eventDescription]
            });

            //Offending Variable
            //var events = [{id:1,title:'this is a title',location:'here and now',startTime:'Right behind you'},{id:2,title:'this is a title2',location:'here and now2',startTime:'Right behind you2'}]



            //alert("done");
            listPanel.getEvent();





        }

    });
```

Here is the events.php Sql and database names have been changed to protect the innocent

```
<?
$dbname = "magicalDatabase";
require_once("../../../db_setup.inc");
If($_POST['panel'] == "list" )
{
    $currentMonth = date("m");
    $currentYear = date("Y");
    mysql_real_escape_string($currentMonth);
    mysql_real_escape_string($currentYear);
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM magicalcalendar WHERE calendar_start_year = '$currentYear' AND calendar_start_month = '$currentMonth' AND calendar_channel_guid = 'CurrentStudentsMain' ORDER BY calendar_start_month, calendar_start_day ASC";

    $results = mysql_query($sql)or die(mysql_error()."------".__LINE__."-----$sql");



    $dayCounts[01] = 31;
    $dayCounts[02] = 29;
    $dayCounts[03] = 31;
    $dayCounts[04] = 30;
    $dayCounts[05] = 31;
    $dayCounts[06] = 30;
    $dayCounts[07] = 31;
    $dayCounts[08] = 31;
    $dayCounts[09] = 30;
    $dayCounts[10] = 31;
    $dayCounts[11] = 30;
    $dayCounts[12] = 31;
    for($j=1;$j<$dayCounts[$currentMonth];$j++)
    {   
        if($j<10)
        {
        $responce['0'.$j]['date'] = date(M)." - $j";
        }
        else{       
        $responce[$j]['date'] = date(M)." - $j";
        }
    }
    while($event = mysql_fetch_array($results))
    {       
        $responce[$event['calendar_start_day']]['events'][$event['calendar_id']]['id'] = $event['calendar_id'];
        $responce[$event['calendar_start_day']]['events'][$event['calendar_id']]['title'] = $event['calendar_subject'];
        $responce[$event['calendar_start_day']]['events'][$event['calendar_id']]['location'] = $event['calendar_location'];
        $responce[$event['calendar_start_day']]['events'][$event['calendar_id']]['startTime'] = $event['calendar_start_month']."-".$event['calendar_start_day']."-".$event['calendar_start_year'];      
    }

    echo json_encode($responce);

}

If($_POST['panel'] == "descript")
{

    $id = $_POST['id'];
    mysql_real_escape_string($id);
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM magicalcalendar WHERE calendar_id = $id";

    $results = mysql_query($sql)or die(mysql_error()."------".__LINE__."-----$sql");

    $i=0;

    while($event = mysql_fetch_array($results))
    {

        $responce['id'] = $event['calendar_id'];
        $responce['description'] = $event['calendar_text'];
        $responce['title'] = $event['calendar_subject'];
        $responce['location'] = $event['calendar_location'];
        $responce['startTime'] = $event['calendar_start_day']."-". $event['calendar_start_month']."-".$event['calendar_start_year'];        
        $i++;
    }

    echojson_encode($responce);
}





?>
```

Here is an example of the JSON data being sent

```
{

"05":{"events":{
    "2856":{"id":"2856","title":"BSM Leadership Retreat","location":"Lake O' The Pines","startTime":"01-05-2011"}}},

"06":{"events":{
    "2957":{"id":"2957","title":"Women's Basketball","location":"Brownwood, TX","startTime":"01-06-2011"},
    "2958":{"id":"2958","title":"Men's Basketball","location":"Brownwood, TX","startTime":"01-06-2011"}}},

"08":{"events":{
    "2959":{"id":"2959","title":"Women's Basketball","location":"Alpine, Tx","startTime":"01-08-2011"},
    "2960":{"id":"2960","title":"Men's Basketball","location":"Alpine, TX","startTime":"01-08-2011"}}},

"11":{"events":{
    "3052":{"id":"3052","title":"Theatre Auditions!","location":"Black Box Theatre","startTime":"01-11-2011"}}},

"12":{"events":{
    "3054":{"id":"3054","title":"Welcome Back Party","location":"New Student Lounge","startTime":"01-12-2011"}}},

"13":{"events":{
    "2961":{"id":"2961","title":"Women's Basketball","location":"Pineville, LA","startTime":"01-13-2011"},
    "2962":{"id":"2962","title":"Men's Basketball","location":"Pineville, LA","startTime":"01-13-2011"}}},

"14":{"events":{
    "3055":{"id":"3055","title":"Organizations Meeting","location":"Cornish Great room","startTime":"01-14-2011"}}},

"15":{"events":{
    "2963":{"id":"2963","title":"Women's Basketball","location":"Clinton, MS","startTime":"01-15-2011"},
    "2964":{"id":"2964","title":"Men's Basketball","location":"Clinton, MS","startTime":"01-15-2011"}}},

"20":{"events":{
    "2965":{"id":"2965","title":"Women's Basketball","location":"ETBU\/Ornelas Gymnasium","startTime":"01-20-2011"},
    "2966":{"id":"2966","title":"Men's Basketball","location":"Ornelas Gym\/ETBU","startTime":"01-20-2011"}}},

"21":{"events":{
    "3056":{"id":"3056","title":"Karen Peck and New River","location":"Marshall Convention Center Auditorium","startTime":"01-21-2011"},
    "3057":{"id":"3057","title":"Chamber Ensemble Recital","location":"Woods Great Room in OSC","startTime":"01-21-2011"}}},

"22":{"events":{
    "2967":{"id":"2967","title":"Women's Basketball","location":"ETBU\/Ornelas Gymnasium","startTime":"01-22-2011"},
    "2968":{"id":"2968","title":"Men's Basketball","location":"Ornelas Gym\/ETBU","startTime":"01-22-2011"}}},

"27":{"events":{
    "2969":{"id":"2969","title":"Women's Basketball","location":"Clarksville, AR","startTime":"01-27-2011"},
    "2970":{"id":"2970","title":"Men's Basketball","location":"Clarksville, AR","startTime":"01-27-2011"},
    "3058":{"id":"3058","title":"CASL Conference","location":"Ornelas Student Center","startTime":"01-27-2011"}}},

"28":{"events":{
    "2857":{"id":"2857","title":"ABIDE - A Reflective Prayer Conference","location":"TBD","startTime":"01-28-2011"},
        "3059":{"id":"3059","title":"CASL Conference","location":"Ornelas Student Center","startTime":"01-28-2011"},
        "3060":{"id":"3060","title":"ABIDE","location":"TBD","startTime":"01-28-2011"}}},

"29":{"events":{"2971":{"id":"2971","title":"Women's Basketball","location":"Richardson, TX","startTime":"01-29-2011"},
    "2972":{"id":"2972","title":"Men's Basketball","location":"Richardson, TX","startTime":"01-29-2011"},
    "3061":{"id":"3061","title":"CASL Conference","location":"Ornelas Student Center","startTime":"01-29-2011"},
    "3062":{"id":"3062","title":"SAI Province Day","location":"JGMB and EDW","startTime":"01-29-2011"}}}
}
```

Also you can view the app [here](http://www.etbu.edu/php/mobicalendar/)

It's best viewed in safari either mobile or desktop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A much more effective way to bind, say, a list to a JSON data source is to use a Ext.data.Proxy which will take care of all the AJAX and asynchronous updating of the list.

I've taken the liberty of rewriting your app to demonstrate:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
        <title>Scratch</title>
        <script src="lib/touch/sencha-touch-debug.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <link href="lib/touch/resources/css/sencha-touch.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

        <script>

            Ext.setup({
                onReady:function(){

                    //DATA

                    Ext.regModel('Event', {
                        fields: [
                            {name:'id'},
                            {name:'title'},
                            {name:'location'},
                            {name:'startTime'}
                        ],
                    });


                    Ext.regStore('events', {
                        model: 'Event',
                        autoLoad: true,
                        proxy: {
                            type: 'ajax',
                            url: 'events.json',
                            reader: {
                                type: 'json',
                                root: 'events'
                            }
                        },
                        getGroupString: function(record) {
                            return record.get('startTime');
                        }
                    });


                    //UI

                    eventListToolbar = new Ext.Toolbar({
                        title: 'Events'
                    });
                    eventList = new Ext.List({
                        store: 'events',
                        itemTpl: Ext.XTemplate.from("eventList"),
                        listeners: {
                            selectionchange: function (selectionModel, records) {
                                if (records[0]) {
                                    eventDescription.update(records[0].data);
                                    eventDescriptionToolbar.setTitle(records[0].get('title'))
                                    rootPanel.setActiveItem(eventDescriptionPanel, {type:'slide'});
                                }
                            }
                        },
                        grouped:true
                    });
                    eventListPanel = new Ext.Panel({
                        dockedItems: [eventListToolbar],
                        items: [eventList]
                    });

                    eventDescriptionToolbar = new Ext.Toolbar({
                        items: {
                            text:'Back',
                            ui: 'back',
                            listeners: {
                                tap: function () {
                                    rootPanel.setActiveItem(eventListPanel, {type:'slide', direction:'right'});
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    });
                    eventDescription = new Ext.Panel({
                        tpl: Ext.XTemplate.from("eventDescription"),
                        padding:20,
                    });
                    eventDescriptionPanel = new Ext.Panel({
                        dockedItems: [eventDescriptionToolbar],
                        items: [eventDescription],
                    });

                    rootPanel = new Ext.Panel({
                        fullscreen:true,
                        layout:"card",
                        items:[
                            eventListPanel,
                            eventDescriptionPanel
                        ]
                    });

                }

            });

        </script>

    </head>
    <body>

        <textarea id="eventList" class="x-hidden-display">
            {title} - {location}
        </textarea>

        <textarea id="eventDescription" class="x-hidden-display">
            <p>{title}</p>
            <p>{description}</p>
            <p>{location}</p>
            <p>{startTime}</p>
        </textarea>

    </body>
</html>
```

This consumes JSON that looks like this:

```
{"events":[
    {"id":"2856","title":"BSM Leadership Retreat","location":"Lake O' The Pines","startTime":"01-05-2011"},
    {"id":"2957","title":"Women's Basketball","location":"Brownwood, TX","startTime":"01-06-2011"},
    {"id":"2958","title":"Men's Basketball","location":"Brownwood, TX","startTime":"01-06-2011"},
    {"id":"2959","title":"Women's Basketball","location":"Alpine, Tx","startTime":"01-08-2011"},
    {"id":"2960","title":"Men's Basketball","location":"Alpine, TX","startTime":"01-08-2011"},
    {"id":"3052","title":"Theatre Auditions!","location":"Black Box Theatre","startTime":"01-11-2011"},
    {"id":"3054","title":"Welcome Back Party","location":"New Student Lounge","startTime":"01-12-2011"},
    {"id":"2961","title":"Women's Basketball","location":"Pineville, LA","startTime":"01-13-2011"},
    {"id":"2962","title":"Men's Basketball","location":"Pineville, LA","startTime":"01-13-2011"},
    {"id":"3055","title":"Organizations Meeting","location":"Cornish Great room","startTime":"01-14-2011"},
    {"id":"2963","title":"Women's Basketball","location":"Clinton, MS","startTime":"01-15-2011"},
    {"id":"2964","title":"Men's Basketball","location":"Clinton, MS","startTime":"01-15-2011"},
    {"id":"2965","title":"Women's Basketball","location":"ETBU\/Ornelas Gymnasium","startTime":"01-20-2011"},
    {"id":"2966","title":"Men's Basketball","location":"Ornelas Gym\/ETBU","startTime":"01-20-2011"},
    {"id":"3056","title":"Karen Peck and New River","location":"Marshall Convention Center Auditorium","startTime":"01-21-2011"},
    {"id":"3057","title":"Chamber Ensemble Recital","location":"Woods Great Room in OSC","startTime":"01-21-2011"},
    {"id":"2967","title":"Women's Basketball","location":"ETBU\/Ornelas Gymnasium","startTime":"01-22-2011"},
    {"id":"2968","title":"Men's Basketball","location":"Ornelas Gym\/ETBU","startTime":"01-22-2011"},
    {"id":"2969","title":"Women's Basketball","location":"Clarksville, AR","startTime":"01-27-2011"},
    {"id":"2970","title":"Men's Basketball","location":"Clarksville, AR","startTime":"01-27-2011"},
    {"id":"3058","title":"CASL Conference","location":"Ornelas Student Center","startTime":"01-27-2011"},
    {"id":"2857","title":"ABIDE - A Reflective Prayer Conference","location":"TBD","startTime":"01-28-2011"},
    {"id":"3059","title":"CASL Conference","location":"Ornelas Student Center","startTime":"01-28-2011"},
    {"id":"3060","title":"ABIDE","location":"TBD","startTime":"01-28-2011"},
    {"id":"2971","title":"Women's Basketball","location":"Richardson, TX","startTime":"01-29-2011"},
    {"id":"2972","title":"Men's Basketball","location":"Richardson, TX","startTime":"01-29-2011"},
    {"id":"3061","title":"CASL Conference","location":"Ornelas Student Center","startTime":"01-29-2011"},
    {"id":"3062","title":"SAI Province Day","location":"JGMB and EDW","startTime":"01-29-2011"}
]}
```

Slightly rough and ready. But it looks like: http://cl.ly/46dH & http://cl.ly/46Rl

Not technically an answer to your question. But does that work?

Comment: Thank you I just updated my sencha-touch.js and got your example working.  I intend to rewrite mine using the Ext.data.Proxy.  The thing I don't understand is where the information for this is I could not find it in the API at all. Also as far as answering the question I am still unsure why my script behaves the way it does but I am going to consider this question answered. Just FYI I am going to rewrite mine not just use your work so no worries there. Thank you very much.

Comment: I didn't dig into why yours didn't work, although the only place you refer to 'events' is in the templates, so my guess is that the structure of what is getting passed into those wasn't somehow what was expected.